# Python pandas with mulitple headers to remove 'Unnamed ' cells, not to remove columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have CSV looking like this:

```
Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 1,WB Report,Unnamed: 3,Unnamed: 4,Unnamed: 5,Unnamed: 6,Unnamed: 7,Unnamed: 8,Unnamed: 9,"26-04-2023 , 09:58",Unnamed: 11,Unnamed: 12,Unnamed: 13,Unnamed: 14,Unnamed: 15,Unnamed: 16,Unnamed: 17
Type,Code,Reg.,Cycle No.,Cycle Type,Cycle Eff. from,Cycle Eff. to,Reason for Publish,Weighed Date,Expiry Date,Item,Description 1,Description 2,Weight,HT,Index,XE
332,32B,ACG,6,Equipment Update,9/26/2022 4:25,,,10/07/2021 05:38,10/07/2025 05:38,BEW,,,118492.295,33.123,498.435902,24.552957
332,32B,ACG,6,Equipment Update,9/26/2022 4:25,,,10/07/2021 05:38,10/07/2025 05:38,BEW  with EO,,,118492.295,33.123,498.435902,24.552957
```

I need to retain the first information but remove all 'Unnamed' cells but not to remove their columns. Make it becomes this:

```
,,WB Report,,,,,,,"23-04-2023 , 08:00",,,,,,,
 Type,Code,Reg.,Cycle No.,Cycle Type,Cycle Eff. from,Cycle Eff. to,Reason for Publish,Weighed Date,Expiry Date,Item,Description 1,Description 
332,32B,ACG,6,Equipment Update,9/26/2022 4:25,,,10/07/2021 05:38,10/07/2025 05:38,BEW,,,118492.295,33.123,498.435902,24.552957
332,32B,ACG,6,Equipment Update,9/26/2022 4:25,,,10/07/2021 05:38,10/07/2025 05:38,BEW  with EO,,,118492.295,33.123,498.435902,24.552957
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) your columns with a custom function:

```
(pd.read_csv('file.csv')
   .rename(columns=lambda x: '' if x.startswith('Unnamed') else x)
   .to_csv('output_file.csv', index=False)
)
```

Output:

```
,,WB Report,,,,,,,,"26-04-2023 , 09:58",,,,,,,
Type,Code,Reg.,Cycle No.,Cycle Type,Cycle Eff. from,Cycle Eff. to,Reason for Publish,Weighed Date,Expiry Date,Item,Description 1,Description 2,Weight,HT,Index,XE,
332,32B,ACG,6,Equipment Update,9/26/2022 4:25,,,10/07/2021 05:38,10/07/2025 05:38,BEW,,,118492.295,33.123,498.435902,24.552957,
332,32B,ACG,6,Equipment Update,9/26/2022 4:25,,,10/07/2021 05:38,10/07/2025 05:38,BEW  with EO,,,118492.295,33.123,498.435902,24.552957,
```

Comment: it works. You are stars

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are you using pandas to read an input file called `file.csv`, you can use regular expression to replace the column names that starts with `Unnamed`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("^Unnamed(.*)", "", regex=True)
```